# Request data of AJAX POST is null in Laravel Controller

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, jquery-ui

I'm trying to send via AJAX data, I'm doing a post and then receiving it on the laravel controller.

I'm getting an error that the data is null.

I tried multiples ways to fix it but I'm not able to figure out how to do it.

Ajax:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $('table tbody').sortable({
            update: function (event, ui) {
                $(this).children().each(function (index) {
                    if ($(this).attr('data-position') != (index + 1)) {
                        $(this).attr('data-position', (index + 1)).addClass('updated');
                    }
                });

                saveNewPositions();
            }
        });
    });

    function saveNewPositions() {
        var positions = [];
        $('.updated').each(function () {
            positions.push([$(this).attr('data-index'), $(this).attr('data-position')]);
            $(this).removeClass('updated');
        });

        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });

        console.log(positions);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'cursos',
            method: 'POST',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify(positions),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            traditional: true,
        })
    }
```

Laravel Controller:

```
    public static function updateOrder(Request $request)
{

    foreach ($request->positions as $position) {
        $index = $position[0];
        $newPosition = $position[1];
        $seccion = SectionCourse::findOrFail($index);
        $seccion->order = $newPosition;
        $seccion->save();
    }

    return response('success', 200);
}
```

Doing a dd of the request, I receive this:

[image]

Comment: You probably don't need to JSON.stringify() the data, and you should do dd($request->all()); and see what you're actually getting

Comment: @justrusty doing a dd I receive the data , Ill update the question

Comment: Ah, you haven't specified keys, you would need ```let positionsObj = {positions: []}; positionsObj.positions.push(...);``` then you would be able to get it with ```$request->positions```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it using `$request->toArray()` instead of `$request->positions` directly